# Should the dominant seventh sonority on the subdominant degree in minor get special attention?

Tags: harmony

In minor - with the raised ^6 and ^7 degrees - we can get a progression like...

```
F7   G7  | Cm
IV65 V65 | i
```

or maybe this...

```
F7  G7  | Cm
IV7 V42 | i6
```

or...

```
F7  bo   | Cm
IV7 viio | i
```

My view of this is the essential voice leading is something like...

```
 ^4  ^4 | ^3
↑^6 ↑^7 | ^1
```

...with the `^3` of `^3 ^2 | ^1` in the inner voices making a nice dominant seventh sonority on the subdominant but not actually functioning as a dominant (it doesn't go to `Bb`).

It wouldn't be right to label it `V7/VII`.

What about its historical use? Did it get special treatment? Like only the result of passing motion or altogether avoided.

Comment: Did you mean to have `^3 ^2 | ^1` in your soprano line showing the essential voice leading?

Comment: I think I see the confusion ^3 ^2 ^1 isn't a proper voice, it would cross parts

Comment: I tried to fix my chord figures and deleted one of the examples - it wasn't what I meant

Comment: In my experience (generally with earlier music, so maybe not that applicable) the raised sixth degree is usually a passing phenomenon, frequently in the context of a `V7` chord.  The subdominant harmony is usually `iv`, not `IV`, and any passage work in that context will use the lowered sixth degree.

Answer (score 1):

My sense is that this progression is much more common in major, but it *does* happen in minor.

Here's one example, starting at the pickup to the third measure of Bach's ["Als vierzig Tag' nach Ostern war'n."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibaBWMajMfs)

[image]

And here's another, this one near the start of the ["Behold, and see"](https://youtu.be/0HnYZPGwV8g?t=154) portion of Handel's *Messiah* (the recording is a half-step below pitch):

[image]

In all of the examples that I can think of, this pattern is used to expand tonic, and as such it just serves a contrapuntal function. You're certainly correct that it shouldn't be labeled as `V7/VII` if it doesn't resolve that way!